# SqlDataReader check checkbox if item is in table

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

Im wondering how to make my checkboxes in column[3]in dtg_ksluzby checked when the value is in the DB.

klisluz(table where I get the data from) contains columns, id, subkey(which is = vyberradek), text, pocet
This is code for inserting into db.

```
  foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dtg_ksluzby.Rows)
            {

                if (Convert.ToBoolean(row.Cells[3].Value) == true) 
                {
                    SqlCommand prikaz2 = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO klisluz(text,pocet,akce,subkey) values(@val1,@val2,@val3,@val4) ", spojeni);
                    prikaz2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@val1", row.Cells["text"].Value);
                    prikaz2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@val2", row.Cells["pocet"].Value);
                    prikaz2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@val3", row.Cells["akce"].Value);
                    prikaz2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@val4", max + 1);
                    spojeni.Open();
                    prikaz2.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    spojeni.Close();
                }
            }
```

Now I would like to check the checkbox when the item is inserted in DB.
Would someone propose me a clue please?

I think I can algorithm this isssue, but I have no idea how can I turn it into the code I thought I can do it somehoe like this :

```
 SqlCommand novyprikaz3 = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM klient WHERE ID_K=" + vyberradek, spojeni); //vyberradek selects row ID
            spojeni.Open();
            SqlDataReader precti = novyprikaz.ExecuteReader();

            if (precti.Read())
            {
                If text in (row where ID_K=number which comes from vyberradek) is in dtg_ksluzby then check the checkbox in the same row 
 }
```

I would like to use this for USER to know which columns did he selected before when he is editing
Thank so much in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 for (int i = 0; i < dtg_ksluzby.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            var row = dtg_ksluzby.Rows[i];
            using(var novyprikaz2 = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM klient WHERE ID_K=" + vyberradek, spojeni))
            {
                spojeni.Open();
                SqlDataReader precti2 = novyprikaz2.ExecuteReader();
                if (precti2.HasRows)
                {
                    row.Cells[3].Value = true;
                }
            }
        }
```

You have to change `vyberradek` accordingly to row content.

Comment: please, let me know when you come back.

Comment: I improved your code and used : using (var novyprikaz3 = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM klisluz WHERE subkey='"+ vyberradek+"' ", spojeni)) and it selects all rows

Comment: back to [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33687/discussion-between-trippino-and-blaze-m)

Answer (score 1):

Try to `count` it and use `ExecuteScalar` as below

```
SqlCommand novyprikaz3 = new SqlCommand("SELECT count(1) FROM klient WHERE ID_K=" + vyberradek, spojeni); //vyberradek selects row ID
            spojeni.Open();
            Int32 cnt = (Int32) novyprikaz.ExecuteScalar();
```

If cnt is more than 0 the items exists.